# Denied twice can I apply again?

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas

I applied for sweden last June 2018 unfortunately I denied. Coz of insufficient fund. After 4 mos I applied again but this time for Malta since Sweden is not my lack, but then I denied due to unreliable source of documents with no further explanation unlike in Sweden. This time I'm planning to reapply again as tourist in Europe. What are the preparation should I have to do? And can I change again my destination?thank you!

Comment: See both linked questions for the best advice we can give.